# How can I create an function to build a table of contents at a marker?

Tags: functions, automation

I'm planning to move StackMode to a literate program once it matures, but until then I'm using the conventional `^L` section markers.

My files look like this:

```
;;; Code:

^L
;;; Section 1 Title

(defun code () things)

^L
;;; Section 2 Title

(defun bleh () bergh)
```

I'd like to be able to add a hook that creates a table of contents at some marker, say `^;;; Contents:$`:

```
;;; Contents:

;;;  1. Section 1 Title
;;;  2. Section 2 Title

;;; Code:

^L
;;; Section 1 Title

(defun code () things)

^L
;;; Section 2 Title

(defun bleh () bergh)
```

For extra fun, subsections could be repeated linefeed characters:

```
^L^L
;;; Subsection
```

Comment: Off topic, is [this repo](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode) the latest version of this package? I was going to do something similar, but if you're very far along maybe I won't need to.

Comment: @Malabarba It is, but I just pushed this branch up (`experiment`).  I expect it will get much farther along than the Org-mode version has been, especially since I now have a well-defined interested audience `:)`.  If you have any resources / ideas, don't hesitate to get in touch `:)` My email is available in the git repo; please use the one listed on `experiment` if you want to get in touch that way.  (Just putting information out there; use it or leave it. `:)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function will find all section headers and collect them in a list, then print the list in reverse order:

```
(defun my-table-of-contents ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let ((results nil))
    (while (re-search-forward "^^L\n;;; \\(.+\\)" nil t)
      (setq results (cons (match-string 1) results)))

    ;; print table of contents
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (insert ";;; Contents:\n\n")
    (let ((n 1))
      (dolist (heading (reverse results))
        (insert (format ";;; %d. %s\n" n heading))
        (setq n (1+ n))))))
```

The `^L` in the regular expression string should be input as an actual control character (`C-q C-l`).